# Read multiple strings and float with multiple cases in C

Tags: c, string, buffer, fflush

My main problem here is that I have two strings and a float to read. The strings' size is 10 bytes, but I should be able to read no matter what input it is and store it inside the strings.
For example:
if my input is `Hello world!` then the string should be `string = "Hello wor"`

if my input is `Hello` then the string should be `string = "Hello"`

Now you might think this is obvious, just use fgets right? But that presents buffer problems when reading a second string. The thing is, I did find a fix, but that involves using the fflush function, but it appears that it doesn't work in a few compilers.

I searched for an alternative and found `while ( getchar() != '\n')` but it actually doesn't work like fflush.

So what I'm asking here is there's a better alternative to read a string no matter the length of the input? This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nom[10] , prenom[10];
    double salaire;
    fgets( nom , sizeof( nom ) , stdin );
    nom[ strcspn( nom , "\n") ] = 0;
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets( prenom , sizeof( prenom ) ,stdin );
    prenom[ strcspn( prenom , "\n") ] = 0;
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%lf",&salaire);
    printf("%s\n",nom);
    printf("%s\n",prenom);
    printf("%lf\n",salaire);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it's actually useful that `fgets` includes `'\n'` when reading input. If `\n` is there at the end of the string, it means that `fgets` was able to read the whole line till the end. If it's some other character, it means that `fgets` stopped before reaching the end of the line and the whole line was not read. We can use this to use the `getchar()` loop to clear `stdin` only if the whole line has not been read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[10], str2[10];
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);
    if (str1[strlen(str1) - 1] != '\n')
        for (int c; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF;);
    fgets(str2, sizeof str2, stdin);
    if (str1[strlen(str1) - 1] != '\n')
        for (int c; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF;);
    
    // Now it's safe to remove the \n
    str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = '\0';
    str2[strcspn(str2, "\n")] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n%s\n", str1, str2);
}
```

You can even make a simple wrapper around `fgets` that does this whenever you read a line:

```
char *readln_and_clear(char *buf, size_t bufsz, FILE *stream)
{
    if (fgets(buf, bufsz, stream) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] != '\n')
        for (int c; (c = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF;);
    // If you want
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect each string to be on its own line you can use this solution:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ReadLine(char result[], int resultLen)
{
    int ch, i;

    assert(resultLen > 0);
    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (i < resultLen - 1) {
            result[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char nom[10], prenom[10];
    double salaire;
    int n;

    ReadLine(nom, sizeof(nom));
    ReadLine(prenom, sizeof(prenom));
    n = scanf("%lf", &salaire);
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", nom);
        printf("%s\n", prenom);
        printf("%f\n", salaire);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Reading salaire failed, number expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```